# Should I be using the var keyword in PHP?

Tags: php

I just reviewed my code and I realize that I never use

```
var
```

However I read

http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php

and it seems to say that one should use var.

```
<?php
class Cart {
    var $items;  // Items in our shopping cart
     ....blah
}
?>
```

In this example what privacy is var set to.

For my purposes I just normally do:

```
private $some_var;
public $some_var;
protected $some_var;
```

What is best practice?

Comment: You should define visibility for every variable, PPP, what you are doing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

var is identical to public. BUT most modern coding standards prefer 'public' over var.

Howevever, there is no real difference at all.

Answer (score 2):

PHP4 used var. php4 had objects just like php5, but php5 did a much better job on working with and extending objects.  Var is not required by any expression in php5 that I am aware of.  They continued to allow its use because they had to allow old code in php4 to run on php5.

In php5 you use instead public,private,protected for all of your object variables.  I believe VAR and public are the same thing technically, and var will be treated as a public variable.

Answer (score 1):

`var` is php4 *only* thing. For all php5 code you need to use proper visibility scope keywords.

Comment: @Hiro Protagonist: ... that's why it's described in `Classes and Objects (PHP 4)` section

Comment: It's still valid, and is very unlikely to be deprecated. If anything, it's simply out of style for new code ;)

Comment: I know but the keyword list does not tell you when you link out to it...in JavaScript most of the keywords are still relevant (there are only 26)

Comment: @Evert: even though it still works - there is absolutely no valid reason to use it nowadays (assuming no one uses unsupported php versions)

Comment: that's what I meant...it's there...to me that means...relevant...incorrectly...unlike JavaScript...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: @zerkms: there's no valid reason to use public instead of var either. It's just a subjective aesthetic preference.. which I happen to agree with ;)